# Way to make this HashMap more efficient

Tags: java, arrays, performance, sorting, hashmap

I have a `class User` that has 3 objects(?) I'm not sure of the terminology.

- an (int) ID code
- an (int) date that the user was created
- and a (string) name

I am trying to create a methods that

- Add a user to my data structure (1)
- return the name of a user based on their ID number (2)
- return a full list of all users sorted by date (3)
- return a list of users who's name has a certain string, sorted by date (4)
- return a list of users who joined before a certain date (5)

I have made 10 arrays based on the years joined (2004-2014) and then sort the elements in the arrays again by the date (sorting by month then day)

Am I correct in thinking that this means methods (3) and (5) have `O(1)` time complexity but that (1),(4) and (2) have `O(N)`?

Also is there another data structure/method that I can use to have `O(1)` for all my methods? I tried repeatably to come up with one but the inclusion of method (2) has me stumped.

Comment: Comparison based sorting is always O(N*log N), and adding to already sorted container is O(log N). To avoid that, you need buckets, the way you now have them for years now. This trades memory for execution time.

Comment: There is no way to have O(1) for all of these. For example, #4 **requires** a linear search.

Comment: @hyde Aren't my buckets the 10 arrays that are based on years?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comparison based sorting is always O(N*log N), and adding to already sorted container is O(log N). To avoid that, you need buckets, the way you now have them for years now. This trades memory for execution time.

(1) can be O(1) only if you only add things to `HashMap`s.

(2) can be O(1) if you have a separate `HashMap` which maps the ID to the user.

(3) of course is O(N) because you need to list all N users, but if you have a `HashMap` where key is the day and value is list of users, you only need to go through constant (10 years * 365 days + 2) number of arrays to list all users. So O(N) with (1) still being O(1). Assuming users are unsorted withing a single day.

(4) Basically same as 3 for simple implementation, just with less printing. You could perhaps speed up the *best case* with a *trie* or something, but it'll still be O(N) because it will be certain % of N which will match.

(5) Same as (3), you just can break out sooner.

Answer (score 2):

You have to make compromises, and make informed guesses about the most common operations. There is a good chance that the most common operation will be to find a user by ID. A HashMap is thus the ideal structure for that: it's O(1), as well as the insertion into the map.

To implement the list of users sorted by date, and the list of users before a given date, the best data structure would be a TreeSet. The TreeSet is already sorted (so your 3rd operation would be O(1), and can return a sorted subset in O(log(n)) time.

But maintaining a TreeSet in parallel to a HashMap is cumbersome, error-prone, and costs memory. And insertion complexity would become O(log(N)). If these aren't common operations, you could simply iterate over the entries and filter them/sort them. Definitely forget about your 10 arrays. This is unmaintainable, and a TreeSet is a much better and easier solution, not limited to 10 years.

The list of users by name containing a given string is O(N), whatever the data structure you choose.

Comment: An alternative compromise: instead of using a TreeSet (which makes adding to be *O(log N)* which can get nasty with many users), sort only when sorted order is required, making first lookup after modification to be *O(N*log N)*.

Answer (score 0):

A [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) doesn't sort anything; its primary purpose/advantage is to offer near-O(1) lookups (which you can use for lookups by ID). If you need to sort something, you should have the class implement [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html), add it to a List, and use [Collections.sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29) to sort the elements.

As for efficiency:

1. O(1)
2. O(1)
3. O(n log n)
4. O(n) (at least)
5. O(n) (or less, but I think it will have to be O(n))

Answer (score 0):

> Also is there another data structure/method that I can use to have O(1) for all my methods?

Three HashMaps.  This isn't a database, so you have to maintain "indices" by hand.

Comment: I see one possible HashMap. What are the second and the third?

Comment: Not *quite* three HashMaps, but you'll get the idea. UserID->User, UserName->OrderedSet<User> (ordered by creation date), OrderedSet<User> (ordered by creation date). Think of this as maintaining DB indicies by hand, or like hardcoding a database engine.